# Clear form fields

Tags: jsf, primefaces

We use JSF / Primefaces in our web application and have trouble in clearing the form fields.

If use the type=reset it clears the text fields but not the drop-downs.

```
<p:commandButton type="reset"  ... />
```

So I tried to change type="submit" and manually cleared all fields in the action.
However as the page has mandatory fields it expect values for them, So I tried immediate="true" 
But due to JSF life cycle this combination update="@form" immediate="true" clashes...

```
<p:commandButton type="submit" update="@form" immediate="true"  ... />
```

Does JSF has any other way to do this simple clear form fields ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if its simplest, but could you try

```
<p:commandButton process="@this" update="@form" actionListener="#{bean.resetMethod()}" />
```

Comment: You're welcome @Jay. Many of the properties have default values to keep in mind (process="@form" and type="submit").